# How to use class name in class scope?

Tags: python, class

I'm not very familiar with Python. So I have some problem while I code.

It's very normal to use the **function name** in the **function block**, for example:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 1:
        return n
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)
```

But when I try to do use the **class name** in the **class block**, things go wrong:

```
class Foo(object):
    a = Foo
NameError: name 'Foo' is not defined
```

Although the code below is okay:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        a = Foo
```

Then I debug these two codes using `print globals()` statement. I found that the global variable dict in **class block** doesn't contain `class Foo` while the global variable dict in  `__init__` **function block** contains it.

So it seems that the class name binding is after the execution of **class block** and before the execution of **function block**.

But I don't like guesswork in foundation area of coding. Could anyone offer a better explanation or official material about this?

Comment: You did not see that you have a recursion in your first example.

Comment: Yeah, I see. And I said it's very normal to use. That code calculates factorial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your explanation is correct:

> the class name binding is after the execution of class block and before the execution of function block.

This is just saying that a class block is executed right away, while a function block is not executed until the function is called.  Note that in both cases the name is not bound until after the object (class or function) is created; it's just that function bodies are executed *after* the function is created, while class bodies are executed *before* the class is created (as part of the class creation process).

This is because classes and functions are different beasts: when you define a class, you are defining "right now" what the class should contain (i.e., its methods and attributes); when you define a function, you are defining what is to happen at some later point (when you call it).

[The documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions) makes it clear:

> A class definition is an executable statement. It first evaluates the inheritance list, if present. [...] The class’s suite is then executed [...]

The class body is executed at the time the `class` statement is executed.  This is different from some other languages, where a class definition is a "declaration" which is not executed in the linear order of the source file like other statements.  (I trust it's obvious why the function body is *not* executed when the function is defined -- there wouldn't be much point in putting code in a function if it just ran right away.)

Comment: Thanks very much. I didn't read [the document](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions) so carefully and ignore the implementation detail.